# Problema al generar todas las combinaciones posibles en python 3. SIGKILL

Tags: python, python-3.x, itertools

tengo un problema algo trivial, requiero generar todas las combinaciones posibles de un arreglo de 37 elementos, donde cada elemento del arreglo puede ser 0 ó 1.

Intenté primeramente usar el método product de itertools:

```
from itertools import product
print(list(product([0, 1], repeat=37)))
```

Sin embargo éste me dió la salida:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/---/Desktop/help.py

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Previo a éste intento había intentado hacerlo correr en otra máquina pero me dió error de memoria (Efectivamente contaba con menos memoria ram que éste equipo), así que, ando buscando una solución alternativa o la solución a este problema. Por su atención, gracias!

Especificaciones del equipo usado:

```
Memoria: 10 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Procesador: 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
```

Comment: Si es sobre linux, podrías mirar dmesg o similar en /var/log (o journalctl -xe si es una versión reciente) para ver quién mató el proceso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el primer caso te sale que el programa fue interrumpido por una señal (SIGKILL),
probablemente porque el sistema operativo se quedó sin memoria y mató el proceso para
liberarla.

Lo que sucede es que al usar `list` para crear una lista, estás intentado crear una
lista de factorial(37) elementos (un número muy grande) y no cabe en memoria. Si
quieres ver cada combinación en pantalla puedes imprimir cada elemento perezosamente,
usando un ciclo *for*:

```
from itertools import product

for comb in product([0, 1], repeat=37):
    print(comb)
```

Esto funciona porque `product` devuelve un iterable, que crea una combinación en cada
ciclo del *for* de forma perezosa.